# Cannot access my computer over Internet (Port forwarding issue)

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

Hello I have a raspberry Pi (192.168.1.100) with torrent app installed and I want to remote the Pi from the internet. Here's my setting :

[image]

However when I tried to access my torrent via browser by using my_public_ip_address:8181 it does not work, accessing the torrent via LAN (192.168.1.100:8181) works just fine.

[image]

I see that my router have other features like DMZ which I disable, do I need to enable DMZ to use port forwarding?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Window 7 on the Pi box? Anyway, try disabling the firewall, and see what happens

Comment: Ohh sorry PI is Openelec, the PC I used to access the browser is Win7. Apologize for the confusion

Comment: Not a problem. Try disabling the firewall on the boxes, one at a time. If it does not work, disable them both and test again

Comment: I tried disabling firewall on Win7 and I cannot find any firewall setting on Openelec. But no luck so far

Comment: Many routers do not allow you to access your internal services using your external IP from the local network.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq: so what are my option?

Comment: Does your ISP allow you to do this?